# Using barman backup on Windows Scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-task-scheduler, barman

I am using barman to back up postgreSQL from a remote server using a local Windows machine through WSL. It is working nicely, but it has to be done manually on a daily basis. I am trying to automate it using Windows Scheduler, but has not been successful so far. What I've tried are the following:

- putting `C:\Windows\system32\bash.exe -c -l "sudo barman backup remote-server"` into a cmd script and launch using Windows Scheduler.
- putting the whole `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c -l "sudo barman backup remote-server"` on the Windows Scheduler itself.
- Making a shell file with `sudo barman backup remote-server` and running `bash -c -l '\mnt\c\backup.sh'`

I am not sure what to try anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure the -l switch will be passed to /bin/bash and as far as I know windows bash.exe doesn't honor it [MSDN Command Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/reference)

Comment: My above comment probably isn't valid. I tried adding the -l switch to my own shell script that is called by Windows Scheduler and the task and script still ran fine.

Comment: I just found out that it is a [known issue for wsl](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1602).